# Ĉu oni uzu pluralon kun “ni”, se temas pri grupo entute?

Tags: plurals

Ekzemple, se oni demandas, ĉu grupo estas kompleta, oni kutime diras: “Ĉu ni estas kompleta(j)”. Ĉu mi aldonu la *j* en tiu frazo? Mi dubas pri tio, ĉar:

1. *Ni* kompreneble estas plurala pronomo, do mi uzu la pluralon.
2. Sed: Se mi dirus “Ĉu ni estas kompletaj”, tiam ŝajnas al mi, ke *kompletaj* rilatas al ĉiu persono individue: *Ĉu ĉiu persono en la grupo estas kompleta?* Do, por rigardi nin kiel grupon, ĉu mi diru “Ĉu ni estas kompleta?”?

Answer (score 11):

Akordo en Esperanto ne baziĝas sur senco, kiel en la angla, sed sur la gramatika formo.

- Same kiel oni diras *kompleta grupo*, oni diras ankaŭ *La grupo estas kompleta* kaj *Ĉu la grupo estas kompleta?*
- Same kiel oni diras *multaj homoj*, oni diras ankaŭ *La homoj estas multaj* kaj *Ĉu la homoj estas multaj?* (Notu: Unu homo ne povas esti multa! Do la situacio similas al *kompleta*.)

Mi ne kredas ke ekzistas escepto por la (plurala) pronomo *ni*.

Krome, la angla, la franca kaj la germana uzas la pluralan verbon por esprimi "Ni estas kompletaj":

- We *are* complete.
- Nous *sommes* complets.
- Wir *sind* vollständig.

(La franca uzas eĉ la pluralan adjektivon *complets*. La angla kaj la germana ne havas pluralajn adjektivojn.)

Comment: Tio havas sencon, kvankam mi trovis en PMEG la jenan: “Iafoje A-vorto rilatas al O-vorto kun J-finaĵo, sed priskribas laŭsence nur unu el la pluraj aferoj. Tiam la A-vorto ne havu J-finaĵon:
• *Tie staris pluraj grandaj kaj unu **malgranda** t͟a͟b͟l͟o͟j.* Kvankam *malgranda* rilatas al la vorto *tabloj*, ĝi estu sen J, ĉar ĝi priskribas nur unu el la tabloj.” Do, tio iom konfuzas min, ĉar *ni* en la kunteksto vere estas rigardata kiel unu afero. Ke estas tia en aliaj lingvoj ne vere helpas, ĉar tio, kio funkcias por aliaj lingvoj, ne devas funkcii por Esperanto.

Comment: Ne, mi pensas ke "ni" ne estas rigardata kiel unu afero, ĝi estas plurala ĉiam.

Answer (score 5):

La frazo estas iom problema pro la uzo de la sence plurala *ni* por ununombra afero, do por signifi *la grupo*. Tio en si mem jam iom tro streĉas la signifon de *ni*, kiu estas simple *mi kaj vi*. La pronomo *ni* postulas pluralan adjektivon, sed kun la adjektivo *kompleta*, la signifo estas tro erariga, ĉar – kiel diris la demandioto – tia frazo sugestas kompletecon de ĉiu individuo.

Unu eblo estas anstataŭigi la vorton *kompleta* per *plennombra*:

*Ĉu ni estas plennombraj?*

Sed mi mem dirus ion similan al

*Ĉu la grupo (jam) estas plena?
Ĉu ni estas (jam) ĉiuj?
Ĉu ni estas (jam) la tuta grupo?
Ĉu ni estas la kompleta grupo?*

Se mi pensas pri reala situacio, kie oni uzus tian frazon, ŝajnas al mi pli klare aldoni ankaŭ la vorton *jam*. Sed eble ekzistas kuntekstoj alitipaj.

Answer (score 3):

Por eviti tiun problemon vi povus diri ankaŭ "Ĉu nia grupo estas kompleta", se la kunteksto permesas tion.

Comment: Oni ne lernas, se oni evitas malfacilaĵojn.

Comment: @Joffysloffy Vi pravas, kaj mi vidis ke pri la gramatiko jam respondis bone Hans Adler. Mi simple volis aldoni alternativon.

Comment: Bone, sed mi jam diris “ĉu grupo estas kompleta” en mia demando, do mi ne vere komprenas la valoron de via respondo.